# Evaluating $\int_0^a dx\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x+a)}x^n$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Is it known in the literature how the following integral can be evaluated analytically?

$$\int_0^a dx\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x+a)}x^n=???$$

where $a>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^*$.

I've tried using series representations and integral representations of Γ(z) and 1/Γ(z) to first obtain a simple integral in x and then consider resumming the expansions. That did not help much. Additionally, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik does not seem to contain the answer either.

Comment: Any background info on this? what is this integral about or what you have tried type of thing that is expected when asking questions.

Comment: @jimjim I've tried using series representations and integral representations of $\Gamma(z)$ and $1/\Gamma(z)$ to first obtain a simple integral in $x$ and then consider resumming the expansions. That did not help much. Additionally, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik does not seem to contain the answer either.

Comment: I wish you would have included in the post, it helps a lot to know what people have tried and have put time into it, rather than just only asking questions.

Comment: I was not able to compute this integral with Mathematica, so if it can be found analytically, then likely some very obscure method would be used. In what context did you encounter this integral?

Comment: If a is an integer then you can write the bottom as a product of factors making a polynomial then maybe use a general pfd?

Comment: For specific integer values of $a$, one can determine the form for any non-negative $n$ using *Mathematica*.  So you might want to ask this question on the *Mathematica* StackExchange site.